# Running Qt app on different computers

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I've just finished my first Qt program. I compiled it with MinGW 32bit compiler.
On my computer I have installed all necessary dll files when I was installing Qt.

After Profile/Debug/Release I can successfully run the app on my computer.

but..
On second computer (also Windows 10) I'm getting errors about missing dll files.
Qtguid.dll, qtwidgets and many more. I tried to put some missing dll files to the program directory. New errors occurred, like 0xc00007b.

What can I do to solve these problems with dll files? What can I do to make this app be able to run on different PCs?

Comment: " On second computer (also Windows 10) " that pc is also on 32-bit? Ensure that you're not mixing 32-bit programs with 64-bit OS or vice versa.

Comment: At first, you need to learn more about native applications deployment. As you see messages about `QtGuid.dll`, you try to deploy a debug program. At second, learn more about [Qt applications deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are compiling your app under Windows, 32bit version it's completly compatible with x64 bits version. There is no problem running the app in Windows 7 or 10 if you are using only Qt dlls.

I recommend you to check [Qt Deployment Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) and use `windeployqt` to get all required dll files. Basically:

1. Compile your app in Release mode.
2. Create a new folder and copy your generated exe file to this folder.
3. Acces to the Qt Mingw32 (or MSVC) command promp and go to the folder  and run:

   `cd C:/myFolder`
   `windeployqt .`

Windeployqt will copy all required files in this folder. When the process finished, just run the app. Compress the folder in rar or zip and test it in other computers.

- If the problem still happens, use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the required dlls. Copy the required files in the folder.
- When all works fine, you can use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.phpElmljRtLb7Jzd3z43Unw&sig2=7u5CNuGV3uGSsc1CVU_BKg) to create an installer.